# Is F countable or uncountable?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

Let $F$ be the set of all functions  $f: \mathbb{Z^+} \to \mathbb{Z^+}$. Is $F$ countable or uncountable?

Define $K: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z^+}) \to \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z^+}}$ for $U \subseteq \mathbb{Z^+}$ by letting $K(U)=\chi_{U}:\mathbb{Z^+} \to \{0,1\}$,

where $\chi_{U}(a)$=$\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       1 & if  \hspace{2mm} a \in U\\
        0 & if \hspace{2mm} a \notin U \\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Suppose $U,V \subseteq \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t. $K(U)=K(V)$. Then $\chi_{U}=\chi_{V}$. Because $U=V \iff \chi_{U}=\chi_{V}$, we have $K(U)=K(V) \Rightarrow \chi_{U}=\chi_{V} \Rightarrow U=V$. This means that $K$ is injective and thus $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z^+})| \le |\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z^+}}|$.

By Cantor's Theorem, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z^+})$ is uncountable, and since $\exists$ injection $K: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z^+}) \to \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z^+}} \Rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z^+}}$ is uncountable.

As $|\mathbb{Z^+}^\mathbb{Z^+}| \ge |\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z^+}}| \ge |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z^+})|=2^{|\mathbb{Z^+}|} \Rightarrow$ $F$ is uncountable.

I'm not sure whether this would be an appropriate method to prove this.

Comment: Your proof looks correct.

Answer (score 4):

This set would also be a nice cacndidate for Cantor'd diagonal argument *directly*: Suppose $F$ is countable, i.e., there is an enumeration $F=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots\}=\{\,f_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$.
Define
$$ g(n)=f_n(n)+1$$
Then $g\in F$, gut $g\ne f_n$ for all $n$.